# Javascript to hide div and href in the same link

Tags: javascript, css, cookies

I have a link that sets a cookie and hides a DIV (intro) when clicked. I however also want it to go to a URL (a href) when clicked, while still running the code to hide the div and set the cookie. How do I achieve this?

Currently I have the cookies code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {


   if (!readCookie('my-intro')) {
     $('#intro').show();
   }


   $('#close').click(function() {
     $('#intro').hide();
     createCookie('my-intro', true, 1)
     return false;
   });

 });
```

(Note there's more code for the "createCookie" function, but I don't think that's relevant to the problem, so I removed it to keep it cleaner).

And the current link:

```
<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" id="close">close and go to URL</a>
```

The problem is with the above, I need it to close AND go to a URL, which I can't seem to set as I already have a "href" with javascript.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: what's the point of hiding the div if you move to another url anyway?

Comment: Creating cookies on the client side is not necessarily the best idea if the cookie controls any sort of site access, because that can be faked by any user.

Answer (score 1):

Just enter your link under the href attribute, and return true at the end of your click function.

Answer (score 0):

You can more-or-less duplicate what a normal `<a>` click does by just setting `window.location`:

```
  window.location = "http://what/ever";
```

Now, that said, it's not really clear what the point would be of adjusting page layout when you're about to obliterate it all anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you properly I would do the following:

Give the link these attributes:

`<a href="http://www.linktowhereyouwannago.com" id="close">Close and go</a>`

And then do a

`window.location = $( '#close' ).attr ( 'href' );`

Comment: With regards to what Pointy says: I would suggest to give the link a proper href, as this is also better for robots crawling your website.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following code-

```
<div id="div1">click <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" id="close" onclick="document.getElementById('div1').style.display='none'; setCookie();">here</a> to go to www.yahoo.com</div>
```

You have to define the `setCookie()` function to set the cookie.